# Order of a reflection in Dihedral Groups?

Tags: group-theory

I'm asked to find the order of any reflection in the dihedral group $D_n$

I'm a bit confused as to what they mean by the "Order" of the "Reflection" since were dealing with the order of an operation.

What I did was looked at a ***triangle, square & pentagon*** and looked at
 the number of axis of symmetry they have which are ${3, 4, 5}$ respectively

So in this case the order of the reflection would be $n$ since, their are $n$ possible reflections in each dihedral group $D_n$

Is my thinking correct? Or am I thinking about this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not what the term means in this context.  Given a group $G$ and an element $a \in G$, the order of $a$ is the least positive integer $k$ so that $a^k=e$ ($e$ being the identity element of $G$).  If no such $k$ exists, we say $a$ has infinite order.  This is called the order of $a$ because it is identical to the order of the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ of $G$.

So, the order of a reflection $R$ is $2$, since $R^2$ is the identity symmetry yet $R \neq \mathrm{id}$.  (It is easy to see that the identity element of a group is the only element of order 1.)